# How to access child directives scope from parent controller

Tags: angularjs, scope, angularjs-directive

How to access child directives scope from parent controller?

I can get the parents scope from the child directive but can't do it the other way round.

ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using an isolated scope, an option would be to bind some object using "=", for example:

```
scope: {
    foo: "="
}
```

Then in html:

```
<my-directive foo="fooInController">
```

Then you can use the variable fooInController and it will bind automatically to directive's foo.

Comment: I'm not using isolated scope as I don't need it to be private, should I use it?

Comment: It all depends how would you want the directive to work. It's a long story - so maybe check this video - https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-understanding-isolate-scope  .Also, I recommend using the Batarang extension in chrome - you can see the different scopes in your app and do some experiments.